# How to run python script on a web server?

Tags: python, django

I have been learning Django, the python webframework, so that I can use python scripts in my website. While I've learned the basics, I'm still a little unsure as to how to actually implement my own scripts into the website.

When I run the script on my computer, it spits out a small graph. Can somebody please help explain to me how to get the graph to be displayed on a web page in Django?

Comment: In the context of a web application there would be something running in the browser which would actually display the graph. Your django app might only supply the data to draw the graph. Typically the front end would be written in JavaScript. You may be able to find some library which integrates well with django.

Comment: @PaulRooney I've been using matplotlib which is really nice for graphing the data that I want to graph. Is there any way I can just have the graph show up on a webpage? My knowledge/understanding of this whole topic is very basic and incomplete, and I may be asking for something that isn't possible without more expertise.

Comment: Maybe something like http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Django.html

Comment: @PaulRooney Thank you so much, I believe this is what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either implement your scripts in your or call the already existing ones in `views.py`. At any rate, I highly recommend that you read the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/), they are a amazing source of high quality materials, including a highly in-depth tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Python script can be run on web servers using the Flask framework. Flask is a micro web framework written in Python. Also Django can be used alongside Flask for building REST API.